# css transition-end no event get fired

Tags: javascript, events, css-transitions

i try to get an event if the keyframe-animation is over, but i didn't get it worked.

perhaps somebody can take a look and can tell me what i have done wrong, i tried it with jQuery "on" and with addListener...

i have put an example on codepen http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/faeAh
i test it with chrome v25

```
$(".addView").on("click", function(){
  $(".content").append("<div id='col' class='column'>view</div>");
  //this doesn´t work
  var elm = document.getElementById("col"); 
  elm.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function( event ) { 
    alert( "Finished transition!" ); 
    }, false );
  //or this
  console.log($(".column"));
  $(".column").on('webkitTransitionEnd', function () {
    alert( "Finished transition! 2" ); 
  });
});

//or this :(
$(".content").on('webkitTransitionEnd', '.column', function () {
  alert( "Finished transition! 3" ); 
});
```

css

```
.column{
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  height:100%;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:3em;
  font-weight:300;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
-webkit-animation: rotateInFromRight 1s cubic-bezier(.70, 0, .40, 1) 1 normal forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateInFromRight{
  0% { -webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:0}
  50%{ opacity:1}
  100%{ -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); opacity:1}
}
```

html

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="addView">add View</button>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're creating the element that will be animated dynamically, you'll need to attach the handler to **that** element like this.

```
$(".addView").on("click", function(){
  var elm = $("<div id='col' class='column'>view</div>");
  elm.eq(0).bind('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
    alert('Finished transition');
  });
  $(".content").append(elm);
});
```

[Updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/igzkl).

Comment: thanks that worked for me ;) didn't know that i have to use bind if it is dynamically created.